# Angular fails to load module

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and I have a strange problem with it. My code is as follows:

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="blogApp">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-controller="blogPostsCtrl">
    <article ng-repeat="post in posts">
        {{post.title}}
    </article>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
var blogApp = angular.module('blogApp', ['ngSanitize', 'ngRoute']);

blogApp.controller('blogPostsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').success(function(data) {
        $scope.posts = data;
        $scope.postsLoaded = 'visible-lg';
    });
});
```

It should be working, as I create a module and then controller for it. But it returns an error: https://goo.gl/UWFMNm. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you didn't install `ngRoute`. It comes separately in its own file/module.

As the error page says:

> ## Using `ngRoute`
>
> In AngularJS `1.2.0` and later, `ngRoute` has been moved to its own module. If you are getting this error after upgrading to `1.2.x` or later, be sure that you've installed `ngRoute`.

[ngRoute Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) - include the file from there for it to work

Comment: And I thought it'll come with `angular.min.js`. Thanks alot!